# Calculate Z score by a given P value

Tags: statistics, binomial-distribution, p-value

I want to find the `Z-score` by a given `P-value`. Usualy what I do is finding it in a Z-TABLE, one of many which I find on google. But, I want to write an algorithm (in code) so I can calculate that value by myself in one click without using the table. I have searched alot and all I found is that formula:
$$
Z=\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}
$$
But as I said I want to calculate the `z-score` by `p-value` only. I will very much appreciate your help finding a solution :)

Comment: What you need is the cumulative distribution function of a standard normal distribution and its inverse, or alternatively the error function.  This should be in a function or library available to your code but depends on what you are using to do calculations.

Comment: @Henry Is there a way to calculate it (CDF) and its inverse by myself? If I want to implement it in my code. What is the formula for that?

Comment: There is not a simple closed formula.  What code/language are you using?

Comment: I'm using JavaScript, just to write a simple Front-End calculator for myself. Also I tried using jStat library by CDN but it did not work correctly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259421/cumulative-distribution-function-in-javascript and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8816729/javascript-equivalent-for-inverse-normal-function-eg-excels-normsinv-or-nor may be helpful.  $Z \to p$ is related to the former and $p \to Z$ related to the latter